# Bind 2 Ojbects with One Single Spring Form

Tags: java, spring

I have Simple Spring form with employee personal info and Contact Info..I have 2 bean EmpPersonalInfo and EmpContactInfo,How do i bind 2 object with "command' and show in empform.
i got this error like Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.util.HashMap]: Bean property 'name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

empform

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form  action="saveemp"  method="post">
<table> 
<tr> <td> Name</td>
<td> <form:input path="name"/></td></tr>
<tr> <td>Id </td>
<td><form:input path="id"/> </td></tr>
<tr><td> Current Address</td>
<td><form:input path="empcontactinfo.currentAddress"/> </td> </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Empcontroll.class

```
@RequestMapping("/empform")
public ModelAndView showForm()
{
    Map<String,Object> modelmap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    modelmap.put("personalinfo",new EmpPersonalInfo() );
    modelmap.put("contactinfo", new EmpContactInfo());

    return new ModelAndView("empform","command",modelmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Path attribute puts value of input field into java properties using java beans convention to be used as `@ModelAttribute` in your controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String saveEmp(@ModelAttribute("employee") EmpPersonalInfo employee) {
  // ...
}
```

if you just want to display the values inside these two objects in that map, you could use,

```
<c:out value="${command['contactinfo'].contact}"/>
```